# Problems with ajax post application

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the following problem I have a wild `<div class="aside_data"></div>` which is populated with information via ajax => `$('.aside_data').html(data)`, the information is of many checkboxes: `<input type=" checkbox" class="css-checkbox category" id="1" name ="cat" value="cat1">`
The problem is that I can't use these generated checkboxes to send data from them via ajax. They are somehow inactive, as if he does not find them at all.
I understand that I am explaining quite confusingly, I will add more information about this, if you still do not understand me, please tell me to explain.

javascript:

```
          $.ajax({
              url:"<?php echo $g['url']; ?>aside-cat.php",
              method:"POST",
              data:{cat:filter},
              success:function(data){
                $('.aside_data').html(data);
              }
          });
```

html:

```
<div class="aside_data"></div>
```

after ajax post .aside_data contains:

```
<input type=" checkbox" class="css-checkbox category" id="1" name="cat" value="cat1">
```

and after this i try to get informations from this checkboxes with:

```
  function get_filter(class_name) {
      var filter = [];
      $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function(){
          filter.push($(this).val());
      });
      return filter;
  }
```

But I fail

Comment: Without seeing enough code, we cannot hope to understand the problem fully. If I have to guess however, it sounds you've got an issue where you're binding events to the checkboxes when the page loads, and so any checkboxes added later don't have events bound to them (because they didn't exist when the event handlers were added). So most likely you either need to use some delegated event handling, or you need to add event handlers specifically to those checkboxes after they've been added to the DOM.

Comment: Hello! Thanks ! I updated my post. From what I've written, I think that's exactly what I need. These checkboxes are generated after the page loads. How can I read them?

Comment: Well first show how the `get_filter` function is being executed.

Comment: `var category = get_filter('category');`

Comment: ok. but _when_ do you execute that? In response to some specific event? Or when the page loads? You possibly need to run it again after you've downloaded your new checkboxes.

Comment: I call them after function get_filter with  `$('.css-checkbox').click(function(){
        filter_data();
    });` and this `filter_data()` contains `var category = get_filter('category');`

Comment: ok. So I'm guessing it's `$('.css-checkbox').click` which is the bit which isn't executing? Because more than likely, you've set that up when the page loads?

Comment: I suggest you read https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/, it'll probably help you solve your problem.

Comment: if I understand corectly the code must be: `          // Attach a delegated event handler
          $(".aside_data").on("click","input", function( event ) {
              event.preventDefault();
              filter_data();
          });
` 
The code works, it gets them out, but for some reason the checkbox doesn't check

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` is not needed in your case. I suggest you read what that function actually does rather than just blindly copying it.

Comment: P.S. I would also write `$(".aside_data").on("click",".css-checkbox"`, so that it does not catch any other input elements (e.g. buttons, radios etc) in the same area by accident.

Comment: Thanks! I reworked it but still when I mark a checkbox it is marked for a second, then it is unmarked itself. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I see no obvious reason for that from the code posted, unfortunately

Comment: I can't reproduce any such issue. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3gh8fjpo/

Comment: Thanks for the help ! It helped me a lot, but I'll have to see why the checkmark disappears from the checkbox

Comment: I think I found the problem. But I don't know how to fix it. I think the problem comes from the fact that based on `filter_data ()` inside this function the data is actually sent and `.aside_data` is generated and de facto when I call filter_data () the checkboxes are generated empty

Comment: Well, I just had a thought: `$('.aside_data').html(data);` will replace everything inside the div, including your existing checkboxes, so maybe that's the problem. In my demo I used append() to add new checkboxes, rather than html() which replaces all the HTML. So I guess maybe you need to do something to maintain the state of the existing checkboxes, and re-generate them correctly checked/unchecked? Or maybe not replace them every time? It's hard to say, since I don't know precisely what the PHP does, or how you are intending it to work.